# How send a command to background using ssh on remote system

Tags: ssh, background-process, netcat

I'm trying to open a port on remote system using `ssh` & `netcat` like this:

```
ssh user@host.tld 'netcat -l 7777 &'
```

but it waits to show output and doesn't go to background!
I tried `nohup` before `netcat` but got same result;

How can I run `netcat` in background using ssh on remote system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ssh -f user@host.tld "sh -c 'netcat -l 7777 > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29142/7211502).

Answer (score 0):

Official version is to use `-f` switch to `ssh`, which will background the whole connection without all the shell magic as explained in the other answer:

> `-f`
>
> Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.  This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This implies -n.  The recommended way to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.
>
> If the ExitOnForwardFailure configuration option is set to “yes”, then a client started with -f will wait for all remote port forwards to be successfully established before placing itself in the background.